# Error -: 'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to return a class that is derived from QObject and I am getting the following error

```
Error : 'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'
```

This situation resembles my scenario

Header File : `B.h`

```
class B : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
        private:
            ...
        public:
            B(QObject* parent = 0);
            ...
}
```

CPP File : `B.cpp`

```
B:B(QObject *parent)
{
//Empty Constructor
}
```

Header File : `A.h`

```
class A
{
private:
     B myClassB;
public :
     B ReturnClassB();
}
```

CPP File : `C.cpp`

```
B A::ReturnClassB()
{
   return myClassB; //This is where the error occurs
}
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong ? Is it a copy constructor issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QObject` class has a [private copy constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).  As such you can not copy instances of classes that derive from `QObject`.  See also [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/object.html#identity-vs-value) on the identity vs. value discussion regarding `QObject`.

If you want to be able to copy instances of `B`, either don't inherit from `QObject` or provide some means of cloning `B` (taking care to ensure that memory is managed appropriately).

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You cannot copy or assign QObjects. And this is exactly what you do in A::ReturnClassB();